# What is $\int_1^\infty du/u - \int_1^\infty du/u$?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I thought that  $\int_1^\infty \frac{du}{u}- \int_1^\infty \frac{du}{u} = 0$ as the two integrals are the same or because we can write it as $\int_1^\infty \left(\frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{u}\right)du$, but my teacher told me that $\int_1^\infty \frac{du}{u}- \int_1^\infty \frac{du}{u}$ is an indeterminate form. Is my logic wrong? If it is wrong, how can i show formally that $\int_1^\infty \frac{du}{u}- \int_1^\infty \frac{du}{u} = 0$?

Comment: That's right. You can't quite subtract infinity from infinity, can you? The integrals above don't exist, it technically doesn't make sense to even write $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{u} du$ because the function $\frac{1}{u}$ is not Riemann integrable on the interval $[1,\infty)$, whence the statement above doesn't make sense.

Comment: To do an improper integral you need to take a limit. The two limits here can be taken independently of each other. If you had one approaching $\infty$ twice as fast as the other, you'd see that the difference diverges. If however you took the upper limits of integration as the same, then took the limit, you'd get zero. That would more or less be a Cauchy principal value. Cauchy principal values are quite special and, in some sense, are a way to make rigorous what our intuition suggests things should be by messing with the limiting procedures in a certain way.

Comment: You can rewrite $$\int_a^b (f(x)-g(x))\,\text{d}x = \int_a^b f(x)\,\text{d}x - \int_a^b g(x)\,\text{d}x$$ if and only if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are Riemann integrable on the interval $[a,b]$, but this also holds for $[a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,b]$, recalling that these would be improper, and thus would include a limit.

Comment: The problem is that I am only taking Calculus and have no idea what Riemann integrable means or what Cauchy principal values are. So, I understand that my reasoning is wrong, but is there a way to prove that this integral when subtracted will giv me 0? Or is this wrong again, and the difference isn't zero?

Comment: For the same reason that we cannot subtract two infinite sums $(1+2+3+4+...)-(1+2+3+4+...)=$ $((1-1)+(2-2)+...)=0$. Otherwise  $-1=-1+0=-1+(1+2+3+...)-(1+2+3+...)=$ $(2+3+4+...)-(1+2+3+..)=$ $((2-1)+(3-2)+...)=1+1+...=\infty.$

Comment: @Vika what I was just saying is extra information.. telling you that what you want to be true isn't and it's only true in a very limited sense.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ok, thank you for your help.

Comment: Does that make $\int_1^{\infty}0dx$ indeterminate?